# Change image if textfield input is matching regex while editing

Tags: ios, swift, regex, string, textfield

I have a `UITextField` and a connected `textFieldDidChange` method in which I would like to check if the `text` is "correct". I have three different conditions I would like to check.

**`textFieldDidChange-Method:`**

```
@objc func textFieldDidChange(_ textField: UITextField) {

    switch textField {
    case passwordTextField:
        // check for upper and lowercase letter
        if (textField.text!.matches("^(?=.*[A-Z]).(?=.*[a-z])$")){
            checkLetterImage.image = UIImage(named: "correct")
        }else {
            checkLetterImage.image = UIImage(named: "false")
        }

        // check for length -> min 8
        if(textField.text!.matches("^{8,}$")){
            checkLengthImage.image = UIImage(named: "correct")
        }else {
            checkLengthImage.image = UIImage(named: "false")
        }

        // check for at least one number
        if(textField.text!.matches("^(?=.*[0-9])")){
            checkNumberImage.image = UIImage(named: "correct")
        }else {
            checkNumberImage.image = UIImage(named: "false")
        }

        break

    default:
        break
    }

}
```

**`matches-Method`:**

```
public extension String {
    func matches(_ regex: String) -> Bool {
        return self.range(of: regex, options: .regularExpression, range: nil, locale: nil) != nil
    }
}
```

I have no idea why the code above is not working. Am I doing something wrong with Regex maybe?? It is never going in any of the `if-cases` ...

***Update:***

The "number-check" is working perfectly fine. The upper&lowercase check is not working at all and the length-check is behaving not the way it should: It displays the "correct"-image after you type something in and delete everything again.

Anyone an idea why that happens????

Comment: *"It is never going in any of the if-cases ..."* -- Are you saying `func textFieldDidChange()` is not being called? Or, it ***is*** being called but your `if` statements never return true?

Comment: it is being called. and like I said in **Update** , the "Number-check" is working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Character sets to the rescue!

Try these:

```
if text.count > 8 {

}

if text.rangeOfCharacter(from: .lowercaseLetters) != nil {

}

if text.rangeOfCharacter(from: .uppercaseLetters) != nil {

}

if text.rangeOfCharacter(from: .decimalDigits) != nil {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your `^` and `$` anchors could be the issue.

Try this:

```
    switch textField {
    case passwordTextField:
        // check for upper and lowercase letter
        if (textField.text!.matches("(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])")){
            checkLetterImage.image = UIImage(named: "correct")
        }else {
            checkLetterImage.image = UIImage(named: "false")
        }

        // check for length -> min 8
        if(textField.text!.matches(".{8,}")){
            checkLengthImage.image = UIImage(named: "correct")
        }else {
            checkLengthImage.image = UIImage(named: "false")
        }

        // check for at least one number
        // could also use  (?=.*\\d)
        if(textField.text!.matches("(?=.*[0-9])")){
            checkNumberImage.image = UIImage(named: "correct")
        }else {
            checkNumberImage.image = UIImage(named: "false")
        }

        break
```

Comment: didn't solve the issue :/ @Rob solution is actually working perfectly fine for me. Thanks your help though